# Multivariable Chain rule Help

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

a function $g(u)$ with continuous second derivative is given and f is defined by $f(x,y)=g(\frac{x}{y})$ for $y\neq 0$ how would you calculate $f_{yx}$.

I am very confused as to how to even approach this question since I am used to drawing dependency diagrams and working from there but I can't seem to make the connections for this question

Comment: Let $u(x, y) = x / y$. Then $f(x, y) = g(u(x, y))$. You should be able to draw a dependency diagram from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you find $f_y=g'(x/y)(-x/{y^2})$

This is a product and you want to differentiate with respect to $x$

$$f_{yx}=g''(x/y)(1/y)(-x/{y^2})+g'(x/y)(-1/{y^2})$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(x,y)=g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\implies f_x(x,y)=g'\left(\frac xy\right)\frac 1y.$$

$$f(x,y)=g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\implies f_y(x,y)=g'\left(\frac xy\right)\frac {-x}{y^2}.$$